# Could not make a comment when reviewing a question.

Tags: support, review

The computer asked me to review [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697023/poisson-statistics). When I tried to enter a standard show your work comment I got a message that it was a read-only question and I could not submit a comment. I opened the question in another tab and was able to enter my comment there. I have never experienced this behavior before. Perhaps it is a bug, perhaps it is a feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither a bug nor a feature: for a couple of minutes all Stack Exchange sites were in read-only mode, with a black banner on top of page proclaiming exactly that. (I only know about meta.SO and Math for sure, but I assume this was a network-wide maintainance thing.) Back to normal process of copy-pasting comments around the site.